# Подключаем БД к сайту

Tags: php, mysql

Подключаю БД к сайту, но выкидывает ошибку.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\ProbaSite\index.php on line 4

Скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее оговорюсь, что делал по уроку (он возможно давний и ссылки предоставить на него не смогу ибо мне кидали файлами), там использовался PHPMyAdmin, но я хочу подключится через SQL Maestro. Выполняю всё через Open Server.

Код файла *index.php*

```
<?php
include ("blocks/bd.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT title,meta_d,meta_k,text FROM settings WHERE page='index'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<html>

<head>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $myrow['meta_d']; ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $myrow['meta_k']; ?>">

<meta charset="windows-1251">
<title><?php echo $myrow['title']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

<table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" sellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="main_border">
<? include ("blocks/header.php"); ?>

<tr>
<td><table width="700" border="0" cellpadding="0" sellspacing="0">
<tr>
<?include ("blocks/left.php"); ?>
<td valign="top">
<?php echo $myrow['text']; ?>
</td>
</tr>

</table></td>
</tr>

<? include ("blocks/footer.php"); ?>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Код файла *bd.php*

```
<?php
$db=mysql_connect ("localhost","root"); 
mysql_select_db ("MyWork",$db);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально у меня Open Server не запускался, потому-что его MySql и мой стояли на одном порте 3306 и мне пришлось переставить его MySql на 3309. Методом проб и ошибок, я пришёл к выводу, что OpenServer всё равно по умолчанию пользуется своим MySlq-ем, а не моим. В итоге решением оказалось отключение MySql-я Open Servera и к возврату в его настройках к 3306 порту.

Answer (score 3):

Проверьте запущен ли sql сервер вообще у вас. Попробуйте вывести значение `$result` скорее всего там `false`. Оттуда возможно и ошибка
Лучше делать как то так еще. В файле *bd.php*

```
$db=mysql_connect ("localhost","root"); 
if (!$db) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```